# Difficulty getting values from .tetml with NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse a .tetml extension file. For this i am using `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

the `didEndElement` give me an exact result whereas `namespaceURI` and `qName` give nil. I am not understanding the exact reason. My file contains:

```
<Word><Text>ËÒ</Text><Box llx="198.00" lly="408.48" urx="244.90" ury="436.56"><Glyph font="F1" size="40.08" x="198.00" y="408.48" width="26.16">Ë</Glyph><Glyph font="F1" size="28.08" x="224.16" y="408.48" width="20.74">Ò</Glyph></Box></Word>
```

Can anyone give me the reason why this is happening, and can anyone tell me how to get  tag value? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't see any namespaces in your xml file. If you made sure you had this set on your NSXMLParser instance:

```
- (void)setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES
```

... and your xml file looked like this:

```
<n:Word xmlns:n="http://www.n.com/" xmlns:m="http://www.m.com">
<n:Text>ËÒ</n:Text>
<m:Box llx="198.00" lly="408.48" urx="244.90" ury="436.56">
    <m:Glyph font="F1" size="40.08" x="198.00" y="408.48" width="26.16">Ë</m:Glyph>
    <m:Glyph font="F1" size="28.08" x="224.16" y="408.48" width="20.74">Ò</m:Glyph>
</m:Box>
</n:Word>
```

You'd see your -[MyParserDelegate parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] type delegate methods called with

```
elementName = Text
namespaceURI = http://www.n.com/
qualifiedName = n:Text
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: for the Key values like <Text>..</Text> you can use JSON framework.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I used foundcharacters protocal method to get that value of the tag.